# Vuforia Active Fusion Provider seems to depend on device

Tags: android, arcore, vuforia

I am currently working on an Android AR Application that utilizes an embedded Unity Project.
The underlaying frameworks that are used are Vuforia and ARCore.
I recently discovered that on Startup Vuforia logs the Active Fusion Provider and depending on the device the Fusion Provider is listed as VISUAL_ONLY or SENSOR_FUSION. The interesting part is, that ARCore Services are installed on all devices, the only difference is the Version of the OS.
I also observed, that on one device the Fusion Provider changed from SENSOR_FUSION to VISUAL_ONLY after an OS update.
So to make it clear, it works on some devices and does not on others.
All Devices are drom the Samsung Galaxy S Series and have ARCore (Google Play Services for AR)installed.
The only issue is that Vuforia somehow does not recognize or connect to ARCore.

Since I could not find any consistent information online regarding my problem, I would like to ask if there are any tips on approaching this problem.
Is this a commonly known issue?
Could it be that not all ARCore and Vuforia Versions are compatible?
Are there any ways to force reinstall ARCore?
Can I use the Android Debug Bridge to check the current ARCore version and status or restart it?

Thanks a lot for you time and Best Regards

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Vuforia by default tries to use ARCore. However on some devices, and for some OS Versions ARCore does not work properly or has some side effect on the way Vuforia uses it. For those devices Vuforia might fall back to its own sensor fusion device tracker.

Also, Vuforia requires a recent ARCore version, if this is not found it will fall back on sensor fusion or vision only (see here https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/supported-versions)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer
Do you know if there is a way to use the ADB to check the current installed version of ARCore or force update/reinstall?

Comment: I know that it is possible via a Native API (see here https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/ArCoreApk.Availability). I am not sure how to force an update though. One further note: I am aware in the past there were some device where ARCore became non functional and rebooting the device solved the problem. However this should be quite rare nowadays.